# Synchronization in threads for Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a home grown web server in my app. This web server spawns a new thread for every request that comes into the socket to be accepted. I want the web server to wait until a specific point is hit in the thread it just created.

I have been through many posts on this site and examples on the web, but cant get the web server to proceed after I tell the thread to wait. A basic code example would be great.

Is the synchronized keyword the correct way to go about this? If so, how can this be achieved? Code examples are below of my app:

**Web Server**

```
while (true) {
  //block here until a connection request is made
  socket = server_socket.accept();

  try {
    //create a new HTTPRequest object for every file request
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(socket, this);

    //create a new thread for each request
    Thread thread = new Thread(request);

    //run the thread and have it return after complete
    thread.run();

    ///////////////////////////////
    wait here until notifed to proceed
    ///////////////////////////////
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(logFile);
  }
}
```

**Thread code**

```
public void run() {
  //code here

  //notify web server to continue here
}
```

Update - Final code is as below. The `HttpRequest` does just call `resumeListener.resume()` whenever I send a response header (of course also adding the interface as a separate class and the `addResumeListener(ResumeListener r1)` method in `HttpRequest`):

**Web Server portion**

```
// server infinite loop
while (true) {

  //block here until a connection request is made
  socket = server_socket.accept();

  try {
    final Object locker = new Object();

    //create a new HTTPRequest object for every file request
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(socket, this);

    request.addResumeListener(new ResumeListener() {
      public void resume() {
        //get control of the lock and release the server
        synchronized(locker) {
          locker.notify();
        }
      }
    });

    synchronized(locker) {
      //create a new thread for each request
      Thread thread = new Thread(request);

      //run the thread and have it return after complete
      thread.start();

      //tell this thread to wait until HttpRequest releases
      //the server
      locker.wait();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(Session.logFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as an academic question, why did you write your own web server code?

Comment: The app displays encrypted content, so basically by creating my own internal web server, I can perform authentication. If an external browser tries to use the same socket I am passing data through, it would not have the proper credentials that I internally supply if the request comes from my app.

Comment: I don't see how that precludes using a different webserver - almost every web server supports IP-based authentication, among other mechanisms.

Comment: I can't argue how its written. I am simply re-writing a .NET based app in Java, and this was the way it currently was coded and it is very secure in its current state.

Comment: Problem is it's easy to make mistakes when coding webservers - for example, if the webserver has a different idea as to where particularly weird requests end than some proxy along the way, you can have interesting security issues. I would strongly suggest using a lightweight servlet container instead...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The web server is the issue right now, it drops one request in a certain instance and I think the threading/authentication is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I echo the sentiment of others that re-inventing the wheel here will most likely lead to a variety of issues for you.  However, if you want to go down this road anyway what you are trying to do is not difficult.  Have you experimented with Jetty?

Maybe something like this:

```
public class MyWebServer {

  public void foo() throws IOException {
    while (true) {
      //block here until a connection request is made
      ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket();

      try {
        final Object locker = new Object();
        //create a new HTTPRequest object for every file request
        MyRequest request = new MyRequest(socket);
        request.addResumeListener(new ResumeListener() {
          public void resume() {
            locker.notify();
          }
        });
        synchronized(locker){

          //create a new thread for each request
          Thread thread = new Thread(request);

          //start() the thread - not run()
          thread.start();

          //this thread will block until the MyRequest run method calls resume
          locker.wait();
        }  
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }

    }
  }
}

public interface ResumeListener {
  public void resume();
}

public class MyRequest implements Runnable{
  private ResumeListener resumeListener;

  public MyRequest(ServerSocket socket) {
  }

  public void run() {
    // do something
    resumeListener.resume(); //notify server to continue accepting next request
  }

  public void addResumeListener(ResumeListener rl) {
    this.resumeListener = rl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. It seems pretty straight forward and I will give it a try as well. I understand the concerns of implementing my own web server I have looked into Jetty already briefly, but did not go forward with it. Jetty still is a possibility for the future, but right now the home grown is performing well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a count of 1 for this. Arrange for an instance of it to be created and shared by the parent and child thread (for example, create it in `HttpRequest`'s constructor, and have it retrievable by a member function). The server then calls `await()` on it, and the thread hits `countDown()` when it's ready to release its parent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try implement this way. Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use a Java [Condition](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html). From the docs:

> Conditions (also known as condition
>   queues or condition variables) provide
>   a means for one thread to suspend
>   execution (to "wait") until notified
>   by another thread that some state
>   condition may now be true.

Comment: Condition variables alone are a bit hard to open-code; you also need an associated Lock and a flag to know when to stop looping around and blocking. Plus there's no need to use the Condition class directly; just use the monitor implicit in every Object...

Comment: Also, to clarify a bit - Condition/Lock make for a more explicit system, but one that is independent from the built-in monitors used by `synchronized` and `Object.wait()`. They would be useful if you need multiple condition variables attached to a single lock, but in this case it's way overkill.

Comment: Actually `Condition` is an interface, I was only pointing it out as using an implementing class will be necessary in practice. The page I linked to has an example with `ReentrantLock`s.

Answer (score -3):

Run under a debugger and set a breakpoint?

If unfeasible, then read a line from System.in?